# How to open a PDF from the iOS SpringBoard (Home Screen)

Tags: ios, pdf

What would be the most straightforward way to open a single, specific PDF file by simply tapping on an icon on the iOS SpringBoard or dock? This must work offline.

I'm afraid it would require a PDF viewer component embedded in a purpose-built iOS app, but I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: Safari can view a PDF, as can iBooks and a number of other iOS apps.  However, I'm not sure how you'll get a PDF or any other document into the dock or on the desktop.  There exist shortcuts on iOS, but generally they're web shortcuts not local files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Upload the PDF file somewhere
- Open URL in safari
- Hit share button in the bottom
- Choose **Add to Reading List** [image: Add to Reading List]
- Choose **Save Automatically** if you want it to available **offline** [image: Save Automatically]
- Hit share button again
- Choose **Add to Home Screen** [image: Add to Home Screen]
- Set a name for it
- Hit add
- Done

Comment: Don't forget to hit upvote if it was helpful ;)